# Ionic 2: Offline HTTP Get request

Tags: http, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am currently loading a list of people randomly taken from the `randomuser.me` api.
When I turn my internet connection off, I'm simply getting a `net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED error`. 
In a "no internet" case I would like to somehow save the http get request and when the connection turns on again, automatically call the saved request. Is that possible ?
Hope I'm clear enough.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use Network plugin. more info [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/network/)

for example:

1-create a service to check the connectivity and add this to app.module.ts providers, so you can access it from everywhere:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Network } from 'ionic-native';

@Injectable()
export class ConnectivityService {
onDevice: boolean;
constructor(
    private platform: Platform
) {
    this.onDevice = this.platform.is('cordova');
}

isOnline(): boolean {
    if (this.onDevice && Network.type !== 'none') {
        return true;
    } else {
        return navigator.onLine;
    }
}
}
```

2- in your .ts file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

//service
import { ConnectivityService } from '../../providers/connectivity.service';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'page.html',
})
export class Page {
constructor(
private nav: NavController,
private cs: ConnectivityService
) {}

 onCallAPI() {
   if (this.cs.isOnline()) {
    //do somthing
   }
 }
}
```

3- finally if you need to check until your device become online again, you need to add a connectivity listener.

Comment: Good resource, but can you include an example, looks easy to write one.

Comment: I add an example.